# Does There Exist an Induced Model Strucutre via Ordinary Equivalence?

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

If $F:\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{C}$ is an equivalence of categories, and $\mathcal{M}$ is a model category, does $\mathcal{C}$ inherit a model structure from $\mathcal{M}$ via $F$?  If not, is there a collection of conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ which ensures that this does work?  It is easy to show that $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the retract, lifting, and two-out-of-three axioms, but constructing the required functorial factorizations is not as obvious to me.  (Apologies if it turns out to be obvious.)

This question doesn't appear to be addressed in Hovey's book.  Perhaps it is elsewhere; it seems a natural enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the relevant structure can be transported along equivalences. Choose a quasi-inverse $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{M}$ and a natural isomorphism $\epsilon : F G \Rightarrow \mathrm{id}$. Then given a functorial factorisation system $(L, R)$ on $\mathcal{M}$, we can define a functorial factorisation system $(L', R')$ on $\mathcal{C}$ by putting $L' f = F L G f \circ \epsilon^{-1}_{\operatorname{dom} f}$ and $R' f = \epsilon_{\operatorname{codom} f} \circ F R G f$.

Comment: Alright, thanks!